# how display data in laravel from multiple values id in database with urls

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a problem, how to get there are multiple in database values.

I used this method it didn't work :

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', function ($id) {
    $user = User::where('id', [$id])->get();
    return $user;
});
```

I used this method successfully :

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', function ($id) {
    $user = User::where('id', [1, 2])->get();
    return $user;
});
```

i want to display the data i want for example 1,2 or 1,3 or 2,1 inside urls

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1,2
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1,3
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/2,1
```

I'm still a newbie in Laravel, who knows someone can help with my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code definitely work for you.

```html
Route::get('/users/{ids}', function ($ids) {
    $id_array = explode(',', $ids);
    $users = User::whereIn('id', $id_array)->get();
    return $users;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the ids as a comma-separated string.

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', function ($id) {
    $userIds = explode(',', $id);
    $user = App\Models\User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
    return $user; });
```

user the above code to convert it to an array then you can get results with multiple users.